# UISearchBar Issue on Table Loaded by SQLite Query

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

First of all, I'm new to this so excuse my any simplest question.
I'm trying to view data and filter it which is very common.
So I use different tutorials. First, I loaded data from my SQLite database, 
then I used custom cell tutorials and customized my cells. But I got stuck in UISearchBar.
The tutorial I followed uses an NSArray to fill the table which is declared in code-behind. Since my SQLite methods gets the data from database to an Array, I thought if I copy this array to the array in filtering methods, that would work.
But it didn't.

Here is some code with explanations:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:allItems];
    } else {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];
        for (NSString *string in allItems) {
            NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                [displayItems addObject:string];
            }
        }
    }

    [tableViewScreen reloadData];
}
```

Code above is for filtering and I tried to copy the array that I used to fill the table to allItems array like this:

```
MyProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
allItems = appDelegate.mySqliteArray;
```

Or like this:

```
allItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:appDelegate.mySqliteArray];
```

But none of them did work.
I'd like to point my problem again,
I have a method that gets the data into an array in AppDelegate class, and in my TableView class, I want to copy that array to another.
P.S. mySqliteArray is mutable array and allItems array is not.
And also, my cells are created by custom cell class, and there are 2 labels in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was defining an array that has objects created by my defined class, I later realized that I was mistaken to carry objects but not strings.
So I updated my code like this and succeeded to create the needed array:

```
for (MyClass *object in appDelegate.mySqliteArray) {
[allItems addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.objectName]];
}
```